# Задание кроссбраузерной верстки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, кроссбраузерность

Искал в интернете [Кроссбраузерная верстка](https://www.google.ru/search?&q=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&oq=%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0)

как в зависимости от браузера задавать стили (вообще отображение)? Я полагаю существует какое-то свойство `propertyBrowserName`, которое принимает значения из определенного списка и сравнивается в `if` или `switch ... case ...`, в зависимости от которого происходит отображение для используемого браузера?

Comment: автопрефиксер, и не страдать....или через сборщики(там настроить)

Comment: Вы не задаете стили в зависимости от браузера, вы описываете стили для всех браузеров, в которых будет работать ваше приложение. Стили для браузеров задаются с помощью определенных суффиксов, таких как : -moz, -ms, -webkit и др.